# how remove black main window in gtk c like in picture

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

how remove black main window in gtk c like in picture.

i want in run program i have one window (window calculator:like in picture) not black main c

Is there any solution?

i use `exit(0)` but not work, exit for window application not the black window

[image: how remove black main window]

Hope you understand me, I'm a beginner in gtk

Comment: Are you running your calculator from a `.desktop` file? If you are, than make sure that there's a line in the `.desktop` file that says `Terminal=false`. If not, then maybe it's in your system's settings for running `.exe` files.

Comment: Where can I find file '.desktop' Sylvester Kruin, I did not understand you well

Comment: I was asking whether you run your code by clicking on an app icon or clicking on the EXE file. However, it looks like you're clicking on the EXE file. Unfortunately, I can't help you there because I don't use Windows. Maybe somewhere in the Windows settings, there is something where you can make it so that the terminal doesn't show up when you run an EXE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2009-July/msg00084.html